# integrating sql select statements

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have multiple sql statements I have tried to integrate:

1 -

```
SELECT b.name, b.address, b.city, b.state, b.zip
FROM b
WHERE b.my_ID =  '8'
```

2 -

```
SELECT DISTINCT room.room_ID, room.number, room.maxStudents
    FROM room
    WHERE room.building_ID = 
    (SELECT building_ID
    FROM building
    WHERE my_ID =  '8')
```

I want the first statement embedded in the select fields like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT room.room_ID, room.number, room.maxStudents,
(SELECT b.name, b.address, b.city, b.state, b.zip
FROM b
WHERE b.my_ID =  '8')
FROM room
WHERE room.building_ID = 
(SELECT building_ID
FROM building
WHERE my_ID =  '8')
```

ROOM table is related to b by - every room has a field, room.b_ID, like:

```
room.b_ID = b.b_ID
```

I have tried adding that into the consolidated statement in several places without success.

I want to end up with a list of all rooms and room.fields ALONG WITH correlated fields, or those fields of the parents, b.fields (b.name, b.address, b.city, b.state, b.zip). b is BUILDING. So every room has a building in which it resides. I want a list of all rooms and their associated buildings. There will be more than one room for each building so I understand there will be duplicate data in the result. Ideally, I want a BUILDING record, then the rooms IN THAT building in the following lines like:

```
Building 1: Address, city,state,zip
<tab/null>room.name, room.maxstudents,...
<tab/null>room.name, room.maxstudents,...
<tab/null>room.name, room.maxstudents,...
Building 2: Address, city,state,zip
<tab/null>room.name, room.maxstudents,...
<tab/null>room.name, room.maxstudents,...
```

Any help or direction is much appreciated!

Comment: You are mixing desired output with corresponding query!

Comment: Why do you need `DISTINCT` in `room`query?

Comment: why not simply `JOIN` these tables?

Comment: where did I use distinct?

Comment: nevermind, I didn't know I had DISTINCT in there. sorry

Answer (score 0):

IFAIK, each query as a fixed number of columns!

My suggestion: use a query like following a parse output in your application:

```
Building 1, Address, city, state, zip, room.name1, room.maxstudents,...
Building 1, Address, city, state, zip, room.name2, room.maxstudents,...
Building 1, Address, city, state, zip, room.name3, room.maxstudents,...
Building 2, Address, city, state, zip, room.name1, room.maxstudents,...
```

For this query use:

```
SELECT
    b.name, b.address, b.city, b.state, b.zip,
    room.room_ID, room.number, room.maxStudents
FROM b
LEFT JOIN room
ON room.building_ID = building.my_ID
ORDER BY building.name, room.room_ID;
```

Comment: that worked. Okay, so the theory is to NOT do a subselect but everything in the main select statement and just identify with a prefix which table it's associated with? Also, when you say parse, do you mean in the loop, decide if the building name is new and if so, print the name, else, print nothing?

Comment: Yes. You'd better add a building id to columns to make better comparison. This is just a suggestion. To concurrent queries also works!

Comment: LS - what do you mean two concurrent queries? Thanks.......If I am sending one query and getting and using the results in MVC, I can get and use one query, thus I am concentrating on getting all needed info in one query.

Comment: If you are using any programming language, you may do one query for buildings, and for each building, make a query on rooms.